# Producer callback in Spring Cloud Stream using StreamBridge

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, spring-messaging

I'm wondering a way to perform a callback using `StreamBridge`, I want to do something similar to `KafkaTemplate.send` that returns a `ListenableFuture`.

Is it possible with spring cloud stream to publish some events using kafka binder and use a callback like onSuccess and onFailure?

example: `producer.send(record, new callback { ... })`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either set `sync` on the producer binding and the send will wait internally on the future completion, or you can configure a `recordMetadataChannel` to get the results of the send asynchronously.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-producer-properties

> **recordMetadataChannel**

> The bean name of a `MessageChannel` to which successful send results should be sent; the bean must exist in the application context. The message sent to the channel is the sent message (after conversion, if any) with an additional header `KafkaHeaders.RECORD_METADATA`. The header contains a `RecordMetadata` object provided by the Kafka client; it includes the partition and offset where the record was written in the topic.

```
ResultMetadata meta = 
    sendResultMsg.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.RECORD_METADATA, RecordMetadata.class)
```

> Failed sends go the producer error channel (if configured); see Error Channels.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-error-channels

**EDIT**

Here's an example:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output-out-0.destination=dest1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output-out-0.producer.error-channel-enabled=true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.output-out-0.producer.record-metadata-channel=meta
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.output-out-0.producer.configuration.[max.block.ms]=5000
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.output-out-0.producer.configuration.[request.timeout.ms]=5000
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.output-out-0.producer.configuration.[retries]=0
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So72900966Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So72900966Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(StreamBridge bridge) {
        return args -> {
            bridge.send("output-out-0", "foo");
            System.out.println("Delete topic dest1 from broker; then hit Enter");
            System.in.read();
            bridge.send("output-out-0", "foo");
            Thread.sleep(2_000);
        };
    }

}

@Component
class ResultHandler {

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "meta")
    void meta(Message<?> result) {
        System.out.println(result.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.RECORD_METADATA, RecordMetadata.class));
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel")
    void errors(Message<?> error) {
        System.out.println(error);
    }

}
```

After the first result is received:

```
kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --delete --topic dest1
```

Then hit enter.

Result:

```
Delete topic dest1 from broker; then hit Enter
dest1-0@0
...
ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.KafkaSendFailureException: ...
2022-07-07 13:36:19.185 ERROR 11735 --- [ad | producer-1] o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='byte[3]' to topic dest1:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownTopicOrPartitionException: This server does not host this topic-partition.
```

Comment: Hi Gary thanks for supporting, with recordMetaData configuration, I can log customize messaging on success and failure messaging on error?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: hi Gary thanks again for the help, could you post an example of this config using recordMetaData logging a success message and another one in case any failure occurs, thanks

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: Thanks for the example gary, last doubt I saw in your example that you used errorChannel to capture messages that occurred in some way error, I checked and this channel is a global channel of errors, there is a way to subscribe to a channel that only receives errors from the producer that is sending the data?

Comment: Use `@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "dest1.errors")` (instead of `errorChannel`).

Comment: Ok thanks for supporting Gary.

Comment: hi Gary, one basic doubt
Should we have to call streamBridge.send() method in separate thread or @Async, so that main calling thread does not get block even for millisecond?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to set `sync` to true if you don't want the main thread to block; simply use the other technique to receive the result asynchronously. The main thread won't block (except for the initial fetch of topic metadata on the first send).

Comment: Thank you Gary, 
i wanted to make sure about this - "The main thread won't block (except for the initial fetch of topic metadata on the first send)".

Comment: I am not sure what you want to "make sure". When publishing a record, the client needs to know which broker instance is the leader for the target partition; to get that information, it has to wait for metadata to arrive.